# rake db:migrate not working with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am using Paperclip, and I'm trying to rake my migration file but I got an error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/Brendon/Desktop/savings/app/models/user.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end
...attached_file :image, :styles { large: '600x600>', medium: '...
...                               ^
/Users/Brendon/Desktop/savings/app/models/user.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...e, :styles { large: '600x600>', medium: '300x300>', thumb: '...
...                               ^
/Users/Brendon/Desktop/savings/app/models/user.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...'600x600>', medium: '300x300>', thumb: '150x150#' }
```

And I don't know how this is affection my rake. There's no unexpected '{'

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  has_attached_file :image, :styles { large: '600x600>', medium: '300x300>', thumb: '150x150#' }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Comment: A legit Ruby syntax error. A symbol and the hash following it appear to Ruby interpreter as completely unrelated.

Comment: That's why I'm confused. The problem is in my User.rb file, when that's not being raked. Maybe quitting my terminal then bringing it back up?

Comment: Most of the application is preloaded during a migration, so a syntax error even there will halt the entire process.

Comment: hmmm... I have an idea

Comment: It's of no use, you'll have to fix that error anyway if you are to boot your application for whatever reason :)

Comment: Actually I can't do it because now running "rails s" it will automatically exit me out because of that error. tf?

Comment: Try changing `:styles` to `:styles => `

Comment: Yeah, that will fix that syntax error. Boring .-. I was hoping the OP would notice that his syntax doesn't make sense and why that is. Alternatively, one can can replace `:styles` with `styles:` for Ruby 1.9+ style.

Comment: now everything's working. Thank you kindly, I guess I was blind lol. I'll thumb up this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a syntax error as noted by the compiler.

This line:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles { large: '600x600>', medium: '300x300>', thumb: '150x150#' }
```

Should be changed to:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: '600x600>', medium: '300x300>', thumb: '150x150#' }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the migration, it's your syntax for Paperclip:

```
 has_attached_file :image, styles: {
```